# RejectedExecutionException in Java Threads

Tags: java

I am writing a multithreaded program in java. I have written something like this

```
exec.execute(p)  // where p is a runnable task working on an array
print array
exec.shutdown
```

The problem I am facing is that the array gets printed giving the correct output but then the rejected Execution Exception comes
I don't understand why when the threads have processed and given the correct output why is the error coming...

Comment: RejectedExecutionException is thrown "when a task cannot be accepted for execution." It's possible that you have a simple error in your control flow, so I suggest you please show us some code.

Comment: Also, which specific implementation of `Executor` are you using?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are shutting down your executor too early. This is an example how I think you should be working.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // the array to modify
        final int[] array = new int[1000];

        // start the executor (that modifies the array)
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            final int c = i;
            executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    array[c] = c;
                }
            });
        }

        // wait for all tasks to quit
        executor.shutdown();
        while (!executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)); 

        // print the array
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```

Also note that working on the same array at the same time could cause **inconsistency** - you must be really sure that you are not doing work on the array that depends on the array.

Comment: ExecutorService.shutdown() doesn't wait for tasks to shut down, it just tells the ExecutorService not to accept any more tasks and terminate. The ExecutorService.awaitTermination() should be called after the call to shutdown() to block the calling thread until the tasks have finished.

Comment: I believe the while loop is not necessary as the 'executor.awaitTermination' blocks itself (?)

Comment: @IHeartAndroid it is necessary if not all tasks are finished within the timeout (blocks for 10 seconds)... Very unlikely in this small example but it is correct.

Answer (score 6):

Problem is you are still submitting new tasks even after calling `shutdown()`. So using `executor.awaitTermination()` won't help.

To fix the problem, check wheather executor is not shutdown at time of submitting task.

example:

```
if (!executor.isShutdown())
{
  executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                         @Override
                         public void run() {
                              array[c] = c;
                         }
                  });
}
```

Hope it helps ...

Comment: In my case the executor was shut down exactly between the if and the execute lines. So if there is concurrency involved you need to put the execute() and shutdown() calls in synchronized blocks / methods.

Answer (score 2):

I used to shutdown the executors created in the runtime shutdown hook

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {

            public void run() {
            if(!eExecutor.isShutdown()) {
                eExecutor.shutdown();
                // await termination code
              }
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

One more option could be get the future when you submit to executor and then block on future by calling get